# How to read data written in http.ResponseWriter

Tags: go

I am looking for update the data written in http.ResponseWriter.

Is there any way in golang, we get pointer/handle to the written []byte and update it before serving the request?

Comment: There is no guarantee that all the data written will be in a buffer. Implement your own response writer higher in the call chain so you can intercept the write calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way in golang, we get pointer/handle to the written []byte and update it before serving the request?

No.